# MouseEnter and MouseLeave event

Tags: c#, events, user-interface

I have a picturebox. it has two event

in MouseEnterEvent:
I do load a panel at bottom of picturebox in which there are two radiobuttons

in MouseLeaveEvent:
I do remove panel with radiobutton from the picturebox

But the Problem is that panel is on picturebox so when mouse comes on panel from picturebox the leave event of picturebox is executed and radiobutton disappears.

I want to remove panel when mouse is removed from actual boundary of picturebox not when comes on panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove panel in `MouseEnterEvent` for the panel which contains your `pictureBox`.

For example if your pictureBox is on `Form1`, in this form's `Form1_MouseLeave` event remove the panel.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like before you leave the picturebox, check if you're in the panel. If so set a boolean flag to false, and check that in the mouseleave to determine if you want to hide the panel.